# how to send a file with a picture from the app to e-mail or whatsapp (25.10.2021)

Tags: java, android

I have tried about 10 answers to a similar question, but none of them were successful. Something might be out of date. Please give an answer for today.

Simple task:
I want my app to be able to send a file with an image to e-mail or whatsapp.

I put the file with the image in the application resources in the folder Drawable.
Its size is 5 MB.

How to do this in Java?

I'm asking for code, not links to similar answers. I've tried most of them already.

Some decisions came to null.bin.
Some don't send anything at all and throw an error.

Perhaps I am not specifying any permissions.
Something else is possible.
I'm new.
I would like an answer with comments (what I am writing and why)

```
// step 1. I put the picture in the folder Drawable
    
        // clicking on the button sends the picture through the messenger to other users
        
public void onClick_sendMyImage(View v) {
    
        // Step 2.Convert PICTURE to Bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image1);
        saveImage(bitmap);   // 3. save the PICTURE in the internal folder
        send();              // 4.sending PICTURE (function code below)
    }
    
    
    // step 3. Saving the image in the internal folder:
    private static void saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap){
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
        //Log.i("Directory", "==" + myDir);
        myDir.mkdirs();
    
        String fname = "image_test" + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if(file.exists()) file.delete();
        try{
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    // Step 4. Sending the saved PICTURE
    public void send(){
        try{
            File myFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/saved_images/image_test.jpg");
            // for something I create this type (so it is said in one of the answers)
            MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            String ext = myFile.getName().substring(myFile.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
    
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType(type);
    
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(myFile));
            Intent intent1 = Intent.createChooser(intent, "what do you want to send ?");
            startActivity(intent1);
    
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "repeat sending", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: to be able to share a file you have save it in storage first and you can fire share intent with the file URL . What have you tried which didn't worked ? add it with question .

Comment: "I've tried most of them already" -- then your [mcve] should show what you tried and should explain what specific problems you encountered.

Comment: ok. done. what else to indicate?

Comment: Make it a boolean function so you are not calling send() if saving fails.`if ( ! saveImage(bitmap)) return;` Display a Toast to if this happens. The user should know about it.

Comment: `Uri.fromFile(myFile)` Dont use Uri.fromFile on Android Q+. Use a FileProvider to serve your file.

Comment: Also stop if bitmap becomes null. `if ( bitmap==null) return;`

Comment: `myDir.mkdirs();` Only call mkdirs() if the directory does not exist yet. And if you do check the return value and stop if it is false. `if ( !myDir.exists()) if ( !myDir.mkdirs()) return;` Dont forget a Toast to inform the user.

Comment: guys, can someone fix my code and post the correct one? (useful not only for me ... and I don't know about the provider yet ...

Answer (score 0):

Sending an image from an app turned out to be not a good idea.

1. The image cannot be edited if necessary.
2. Over time, you may want to add more images, etc..

I did it differently, and it turned out better:

1. I put the image on GoogleDisk.(now I can change it at any time without having
   to ask users to reinstall the application every time the picture changes).
2. I placed a link to the picture in the FireBase Database. (I also placed a banner with a picture here.).
3. I connected the application to the Firebase Database.
4. In the activity I made a RecyclingView, where I get a banner(s) and a link(s) to the original image(s). The user can download this link or send it through whatsapp anywhere and download the original picture in good quality (A1, 2.5Mb).

---

thanks, guys..

I thank the guys for the tips, especially mr.Blackapps. In this case, you really can't do without a FileProvider.